# Parsing JSON string to dictionary swift

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access the individual member-fields of a JSON object in `PHP` from a JSON string but I can't to access the inner-json, all I get is `Array`.

This is the `JSON string`

```
 data =     (
            {
        "created_time" = "2018-10-07T04:42:39+0000";
        id = 1069496473131329;
        name = "NAME_0";
    },
            {
        "created_time" = "2018-09-09T10:31:50+0000";
        id = 955684974605664;
        name = "NAME_1";
    },
```

At the moment my code is:

```
$nameString = $_POST["nameData"];
$nameJsonString = json_encode($nameString, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$jsonNameObj = json_decode($nameJsonString, true);
```

I've been trying to access the individual entry with:

```
    $element = $jsonNameObj['data'][0];
```

But only receive `Array`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers :)

Comment: is "$jsonLikeObj" supposed to be "$jsonNameObj?" Because I don't see where you're getting "$jsonLikeObj" from the code shown above.

Comment: @Difster correct, edited then. Copy-paste error

Comment: Something else I'm unclear about. Does $_POST["nameData"]  contain the JSON above starting with data = ?

Comment: $element = $jsonNameObj['data'][0]['created_time'];

Comment: @Difster yes, it's a JSON string sent from a client.

Comment: Next question, why are you encoding it as json, then decoding it again?

Comment: @Difster $_POST["nameData"] is in the form of an array so I understood it that I had to encode it to a JSON first

Comment: $element = $jsonNameObj->['data'][0]->created_time;

Comment: $_POST['nameData'] is an element of an array but if it contains json, then treat it directly as json.

Just as if $_POST['some_name'] contained a person's name, that value of that element would just be a string.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the inputted JSON data, I've realised that it doesn't have a consistent form. As opposed to the overall structure being:

```
JSON -> List -> JSON
```

Instead, it's:

```
JSON -> List
```

The list contains individual elements that can be in a different order. Consequently, calling:

```
$element = $jsonNameObj['data'][0]['created_time'];
```

Works sometimes. As there are three-values/object, I can congregate these values into a trio.

I'm sure there's a way to condense this list into a fixed-JSON format but I'm not familiar with how I'd go about that.

At the moment, with a bit of logic on the back-end, I can retrieve the values.

Thanks for your help @Difster and @Osama!